# Setting Custom Wordpress "Posts page” AS “Front page"

Tags: customization, page-template, frontpage, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

While I don’t necessarily wish to establish a "**STATIC**" Front page, I **would like** to employ a custom page as BOTH my "Posts page" and my "Front page".   I’ve created a PAGE titled "Teaching Kids To…" with a "Page of Posts" type template to serve as my "Posts page."  Doing so,  facilitates

1. Titling my "Posts page" (or blog page) as something other than "**Home**"
2. Utilization of a custom template (if so desired)
3. Option to add custom fields (if so desired)
4. Option to tweak and monitor the page via Yoast WordPress SEO plugin,
   for blog specific focus keywords (e.g. "Teaching Kids to").

Trouble is… while I would also like for this page to be my home page (or page_on_front) WordPress complains when I try to select the same page for both "Front page" and "Posts page" under Settings->Reading, **AND** navigation on the front end actually breaks down if I try to simply ignore the WordPress warnings.

Surely someone has discovered a suitable work-around?

Comment: You should be able to merely create a page with your custom template and then select it as your "static" front page. Just leave the posts page option blank if this page displays your posts anyways.

Comment: @Ronburgundy
True as that is, this also REQUIRES one to specify a "Posts page" resulting in MULTIPLE "Blog" or "Posts" pages. (e.g. the one specified as "Front page" and the one specified as "Posts page".)  Hence, my post here...

Comment: So the way you have your template setup you NEED to have a posts page and a front page? Well Just create two seperate pages using the same template, and set one to the static page, and one to the posts page. That should work assuming I understand the issue correctly.

Comment: @Ronburgundy blasted internet disinformation! Somewhere just this morning I read that leaving the posts page option blank was... well... not an option. My bad, because... well... it never occurred to me to even try.  Low and Behold, yes you can,  and that actually solves my problem, THANK YOU!

Comment: Excellent, I am going to add that suggestion as a answer, and then you can accept the answer so i can get some rep :D if u dont mind. To accept a answer you just click the green check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> You should be able to merely create a page with your custom
>   template and then select it as your "static" front page. Just leave
>   the posts page option blank if this page displays your posts anyways.

Comment: Doh! Perhaps I spoke too soon (my bad again?) but... while I find I am in fact able to leave the posts page option blank, no content is returned on the page regardless of what template I select for it (Default or otherwise). Default, and other templates return blog posts ONLY when the page is selected as Posts page. Net result, I get a home page with no content, and NO Posts/Blog page.   Meanwhile, have_posts() returns true (whatever template), but what fails after that completely eludes me.

Comment: Aha! Selecting the desired page as the "Posts page" while leaving the "Front page" option blank actually seems to do the trick, though I'm looking to verify whether or not this will override page order moving the selected page into the first (home) position of the pages list.  I would post this in answer to my own question but apparently I don't have enough rep myself. Anyway... I'd +1 to Ron for pointing me in the right general direction, but again... I don't have enough rep.

Comment: At least you seem to have it working. That is a plus lol.